# dd primary partition slow transfer rate

Tags: partition, backup, dd

Can someone explain me why if backup ,using `dd`, a primary partition to a primary partition on other disk the transfer rate (MB/s) is significantly slower compared to the the rate I have if the destination is a logical partition.

Let's say that I have two disk `sda` and `sdb` and I want to backup `sda1` a primary partion of `sda`, on `sdb`. I create a new partition on `sdb` that has the same size of `sda1`.

If the partion on sdb is primary When I run

```
dd  if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1
```

the speed is 20 MB/s but if I launch using a logical partition as destination

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb5
```

the speed is 3 MB/s. To copy at the same speed I need to set the `BS=4MB` .

I run the test more the one time also after rebooting the machine.

Comment: what variance do you have? Have you tested several times? Rebooted in between so file system cache is away? What is your bottleneck, the reading part or the writing part? What does your first sentence mean? What does your last sentence mean? What happens if you set BS=4MB? What happens if you set bs instead?

Comment: It's completely normal for `dd` to be slow if you don't set `bs=1M` or similar. The default blocksize is 512 bytes which causes way too much syscall overhead. Also, HDDs are fastest at the beginning and slowest at the end, so if your sdb5 partition starts in the middle of the disk it will be slightly slower than sdb1 at the beginning of the disk.

Comment: Can you include the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` please?

Comment: Actually the disk is sdc anyway, Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: What's the alignment of the partitions? That is important, too. But do add bs=1M for things like this, _really_.